# mysql replace within phpmyadmin gives error

Tags: mysql, replace, sql-update

In following sql query I get an error on replace row.
What is wrong I do not get.
Probably phpmyadmin does not work with ' single code.
I also try ` does not work eather.

Does someone has a solution for this?

```
UPDATE   `wp_postsbck` 
SET `post_content` =  REPLACE(
'<p style="font-size: 17px; line-height: 27px; margin-top: 10px;">',
'<p>')
WHERE
`guid` = 'http://xxxx/?page_id=329'
```

Tryed this also:

```
UPDATE   `wp_postsbck` 
SET `post_content` =  REPLACE(
'<p style=\"font-size: 17px; line-height: 27px; margin-top: 10px;\">',
'<p>')
WHERE
`guid` = 'http://xxxx/?page_id=329'
```

Thanks

Oeps... I forgot a part! Sorry first part (field) not written.

Comment: `REPLACE` takes three arguments. You have only supplied two. See the MySQL reference [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Comment: So it should be `SET post_content =  REPLACE(post_content,
'<p style="font-size: 17px; line-height: 27px; margin-top: 10px;">',
'<p>')`

Answer (score 1):

As seen in [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) the right syntax of the *REPLACE* function is:

```
REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)
```

so you need to provide 3 arguments to the function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I was blind! Complete forgotten the write 3 parts in statement.
I will have a coffee break.